# Authorize parou de funcionar

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Segue os meus códigos

Login :

```
public ActionResult Login(login login, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (new AllFictionMembershipProvider().ValidateUser(login.email, login.senha))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.email,false);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
 
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(login);
    }
```

Membership provider

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            EntidadesAllFictionBD db = new EntidadesAllFictionBD();

            var query = (from l in db.login
                         where l.email == username && l.senha == password
                         select l).SingleOrDefault();
            if (query==null) {
                return false;
            }

            else {

                return true;
            }

            }
```

Role provider:

```
 {
        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            using (EntidadesAllFictionBD db = new EntidadesAllFictionBD())
            {
                usuario user = db.usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.email.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

                var permissao = from p in db.permissao
                                from u in db.usuario
                                where p.idpermissao==u.usuario_idpermissao
                                    select p.permissao1;

                if (permissao != null)

                    return permissao.ToArray();
                else
                    return new string[] { }; ;
            }
        }
        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            using (EntidadesAllFictionBD db = new EntidadesAllFictionBD())
            {
                usuario user = db.usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.email.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

                var permissao = from p in db.permissao
                                from u in db.usuario
                                where p.idpermissao == u.usuario_idpermissao
                                select p.permissao1;
                if (user != null)
                    return permissao.Any(p => p.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

E esse é o controller que eu quero bloquear:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
    public class BancaController : Controller
```

Ontem, ao acessar qualquer action desse controller, era mostrado um formulário de login, e qualquer usuário que não possuísse a permissão admin, era redirecionado para a pagina de usuário. Hoje, quando eu acesso essa pagina, ele exibe o mesmo formulário de login, porém, qualquer usuário pode acessar as actions agora.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Não fiz nenhuma mudança de ontem para hoje.

Comment: Nem trocou a role do usuário para fazer um outro teste e esqueceu de voltar a uma role que não seja de admin?

Comment: Também não. Só adicionei um usuário com a permissão de admin. Porém, só estou logando com o usuário que possuí a permissão user.

Comment: @RyanSantos Já colocou um breakpoint na primeira linha de `GetRolesForUser` pra ver o que está acontecendo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Então, eu consigo visualizar o email de quem está tentando acessar, mas não consigo visualizar os valores dos outros atributos.

Comment: Descobri o problema, só não sei resolve-lo. Quando eu adiciono um usuario com permissão de admin, por algum motivo, todos outros usuarios ganham o mesmo acesso, mesmo que ele tenha uma permissão de usuario comum. Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: @RyanSantos Atualize sua pergunta com o método `AddUsersToRoles` do seu `RoleProvider`, por favor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu não cheguei a implementar esse método. Como estava carregando as roles direto do banco, achei que não seria necessário.

Comment: É aí que está a raiz do seu problema. Possivelmente alguma coisa está inserindo permissões para todo e qualquer usuário inserido.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Entendi. Vou implementar aqui.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Estou com o erro Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to int nessa linha aqui    userRole.UserRoleId = Guid.NewGuid(); Estou utilizando um daqueles exemplos que você postou na pergunta sobre o login. Você quer que eu realize uma nova pergunta, ou você poderia responder por aqui mesmo? Valeu.

Comment: @RyanSantos Simplesmente remova a linha que funciona.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez De fato. Consegui resolver, agora cada usuário tem de fato sua permissão. Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas formalizando uma resposta:

Verifique o método `AddUsersToRoles` do seu `RoleProvider`. Aparentemente é um bug na implementação dele.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que seu select está trazendo todas as permissões de todos os usuários, já chegou a debugar o retorno dele?

```
var permissao = from p in db.permissao
                from u in db.usuario
                where p.idpermissao==u.usuario_idpermissao
                select p.permissao1;
```

Não conheço sua estrutura, mas talvez o correto seja usar um join:

```
var permissao = from u in db.usuario
                join p in db.permissao on p.idpermissao equals u.usuario_idpermissao
                where u.id == user.id
                select p.permissao1;
```